# I am getting runtime error in this code: https://leetcode.com/problems/range-sum-query-2d-immutable/submissions/

Tags: python-3.x

```
 class NumMatrix:

    def __init__(self, matrix: List[List[int]]):
        m = len(matrix)
        n = len(matrix[0])
        PSUM = []   
        for i in range(m):
            for j in range(1,n):
                matrix[i][j] += matrix[i][j-1]
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(1,m):
                matrix[i][j]+= matrix[i-1][j]
        
                
        

    def sumRegion(self, row1: int, col1: int, row2: int, col2: int) -> int:
        ans = 0
        ans += self.matrix[row2][col2]
        if col1>=1:
            ans+= self.matrix[row2][col1-1]
        if row1>=1:
            ans+= self.matrix[row1][col2]
        if row1>=1 and col1>=1:
            ans+= self.matrix[row1-1][col1-1]
        return ans
        
        
        


# Your NumMatrix object will be instantiated and called as such:
# obj = NumMatrix(matrix)
# param_1 = obj.sumRegion(row1,col1,row2,col2)
```

#Added in the title I am getting runtime error in this code: https://leetcode.com/problems/range-sum-query-2d-immutable/submissions/
https://leetcode.com/problems/range-sum-query-2d-immutable/submissions/

> Error: AttributeError: 'NumMatrix' object has no attribute 'matrix'
> ans += self.matrix[row2][col2] Line 19 in sumRegion (Solution.py)
> result = obj.sumRegion( Line 42 in **helper_select_method** (Solution.py)
> ret.append(**DriverSolution**().**helper_select_method**(method, params[index], obj)) Line 83 in _driver (Solution.py)
> _driver() Line 92 in  (Solution.py)

Comment: Please add the full traceback

Comment: Added. Please check

Answer (score 0):

In `__init__`, you are getting the `matrix` variable as an argument. That variable is in the function scope so it is limited to the function. In `sumRegion`, I assume you are trying to get that matrix variable from `self`, but you never set the variable.

This can be easily solved by inserting `self.matrix = matrix` in the first line of `__init__`